# How to make a look-up table if a 2D array already has been given?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have a 2D array which I name it as a look-up table as follows:

```
123   256   19   52369564875214
147   307   51   12654987625425
136   94    14   65913210210871
301   818   23   74120032154894
215   103   81   54680045569748
...
```

... and so on (size of the array is 700x4)

The aim of this work is to ask user to enter three numbers, say a, b, and c. 
This code should then look at the table (the array above) and return the corresponding value d, where d is extracted from the last column. For example if user enters (147,307,51), then the code should give the user 12654987625425. In fact as a function f(a,b,c)=f(147,307,51)=12654987625425.

```
package arrayread;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayRead {
    //  
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ArrayRead ar = new ArrayRead();
        ar.readArray("C:/Users/Desktop/tsp2.txt",",");
        String arr[][] = ar.getArray();
        int rows = ar.getRows();
        int cols = ar.getCols();

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                System.out.print(arr[r][c]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }

    private String arr[][];
    private int rows, cols;

    String[][] getArray()
    {
        return arr;
    }

    int getRows()
    {
        return rows;
    }

    int getCols()
    {
        return cols;
    }

    // Read using DELIMITER TAB
    void readArray(String arrayName)
    {
        rows = 0;
        cols = 0;
        int r, c, numElements;
        String ipString, splitString[];
        ArrayList <String>tmpArr = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(arrayName));
            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                ipString = in.nextLine();
                splitString = ipString.split("\t");
                if (rows==0)
                {
                    cols = splitString.length;
                }
                for (c=0;c<cols;c++)
                {
                    tmpArr.add(splitString[c]);
                }
                rows++;
            }
            in.close();

            arr = new String[rows][cols];
            numElements = 0;
            for (r=0; r<rows; r++)
            {
                for (c=0; c<cols; c++)
                {
                    arr[r][c] = tmpArr.get(numElements);
                    numElements++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occurred!");
        }
    }

    // Read using DELIMITER regex
    void readArray(String arrayName, String regex)
    {
        rows = 0;
        cols = 0;
        int r, c, numElements;
        String ipString, splitString[];
        ArrayList <String>tmpArr = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(arrayName));
            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                ipString = in.nextLine();
                splitString = ipString.split(regex);
                if (rows==0)
                {
                    cols = splitString.length;
                }
                for (c=0;c<cols;c++)
                {
                    tmpArr.add(splitString[c]);
                }
                rows++;
            }
            in.close();

            arr = new String[rows][cols];
            numElements = 0;
            for (r=0; r<rows; r++)
            {
                for (c=0; c<cols; c++)
                {
                    arr[r][c] = tmpArr.get(numElements);
                    numElements++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occurred!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/ and cut your example down to a smaller example.

Comment: You can presort the 2d array and then use binary search for value lookup.

Comment: Also, *please* indent your code properly!

Answer (score 0):

so essentially, if I understand correctly, that you're given arr[x][0,1,2] and you want to return arr[x][3]

If that's the case, what you do is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 700; i++){
    if(arr[i][0] == entry1 && arr[i][1] == entry2 && arr[i][2] == entry3)
        return arr[i][3];
}
```

Edit:
To read from command line, you need to do:

```
//  open up standard input
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try{
    int entry1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int entry2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int entry3 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}catch(IOException ioe){
    // handle exception
}
```

PS: sorry for the delay

Comment: Dear Jamil, thank you for your reply. As I said I am not good in Java. Please let me apply your suggestion to see if it works or not. I will get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Jamil, the use should enter the three inputs to get the result (last column=result). Your code is correct, however, I am not sure how to define entry1 to entry3. Can you please see if it is what you mean?